# How can I bring a div above the current front-most (z-index: 0) div?

Tags: html, css, z-index, svelte

I'm building a gauge which uses pure CSS. It has a background to clip the remainder of the progress colour from showing. I want to add another div on top which gives a text indication of the progress: "10%".

It seems like no matter what I do, I end up with the background clip covering my text.

I've got an example of the problem here:

https://svelte.technology/repl?version=1.60.3&gist=77e1b55c23e229dee8d45b5648610593

An extremely cut down version of my code, demonstrating the problem is as follows:

```
<div class="gauge-wrap">
    <div class="gauge-core">
        <div class="gauge-bg" style="background-color: #fff;">
            <div class="gauge-bg-value">10 %</div>
        </div>
        <div class="gauge-cap" style="background-color: #000;"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
.gauge-bg-value {
  position: relative;
  color: #f0f;
  top: 7px;
  z-index: 6;
}

.gauge-wrap {
  position:relative;
  margin:0 0 20px;
}

.gauge-bg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius:100px;
  z-index:0;
}

.gauge-cap {
  position: absolute;
  top:16px;
  left:16px;
  width: 168px;
  height: 168px;
  z-index:5;
}
</script>
```

It seems like z-index: 0 is still on top of my text div (.gauge-bg-value), even though I've given it a higher index.

Update - Solution:

In building my example, I moved the text into the `.gauge-cap` div and now it sits on top. Perhaps it was that div covering it all along. Happy to hear solutions that don't modify the structure of the html though.

Comment: Please read 
[Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) And then create a [mcve] in the question itself

Comment: Thanks @Pete - valid point, I'll update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to do with [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context). In a case like this...

```html
<div class='foo'>
  <div class='bar'></div>
</div>

<div class='baz'></div>
```

...if `foo` and `baz` both create stacking contexts, and `baz` has a higher z-index than `foo`, then `bar` can never appear above `baz` no matter what. You'll have to break your markup apart into different layers instead (though in your example, I think you'd have an easier time using SVG instead of HTML).

Comment: Thanks - when you put it like that, it makes a lot of sense!